# How does Jfrog Pipelines' GitRepo Include and Exclude files works? Which takes precedence?

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

I want to create a GitRepo resource in my pipelines but want to use combination of include and exclude files. But I am unclear on precedence!

If the pattern I give matches with both include and exclude - how does it work?

```
  - name: platform_pr
    type: GitRepo
    configuration:
      gitProvider: myGithub
      path: dev/helm-values
      files:
        include: m*
        exclude: ma*
      branches:
        include: ^master$
      buildOn:
        commit: true
```

Answer (score 2):

The current behavior for [GitRepo resource](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/GitRepo) in pipelines is as follows:

- Take all files impacted by the commit
- Remove all files that **DON'T** match the included pattern
- Remove all files that **DO** match the excluded pattern
- If any files are left, the resource is updated